# UWP Webview: CSS :hover support?

Tags: webview, uwp

I have a webview in my UWP application, that shows some text. Some of the text is clickable (). I have tried adding the following CSS and including that in the HTML, but it does not seem to work.

```
a:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

Does webview support hover in a UWP application? I have been unable to find any information regarding this.

EDIT:
Here is the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-size: 10pt;
        color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFFFFF;
      }
      .link:hover {
        background-color: red;
      } 
      .linenumber {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class='link'>
      <div>
        <div class='linenumber'>1</div>
        Alpha
      </div>
    </a>
    <a class='link'>
      <div>
        <div class='linenumber'>2</div>
        Beta
      </div>
    </a>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) { 
        document.links[i].onclick = function() { 
          window.external.notify(this.href); 
          return false; 
        } 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
}
```

Comment: Does the following css work in your side?

Comment: No, it did not work. I have added my HTML to the top post.

Answer (score 0):

> UWP Webview: CSS :hover support?

UWP Webview support css `:hover` tag, you could place style in the html like the following. and load html with `ms-appx-web` uri scheme.

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
   a:hover{
       color:red;
   }
</style>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello Html</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" >Click Me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <WebView Source="ms-appx-web:///TestPage.html"/>
</Grid>
```

**Update**

```
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
        font-size: 18pt;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .link {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000;
    }
    .link:hover{
        color:red;
    }
    .linenumber {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        min-width: 50px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Does not work for me. I have added the HTML code to the top post.

Comment: Please use the style where in the update part. it [woks](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYAfMNjt1VEbmLMjA?e=abceLA) in my side.

Comment: Does not for me. Could it be that I build my HTML with a StringBuilder? The content is highly dynamic, so I need to do it thay way.

Comment: You need to edit your style, the text color same as body color that will make the text hidden.   if you want to edit the hover color please use `.link:hover{ color:red; }` but not `background-color`.

Comment: Color did not work either. Nothing I put in the :hover style applies when I hover over a link.

Comment: Have you checked this [screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgYYAfMNjt1VEbmLMjA?e=abceLA)?

Comment: I did, but that is not how it looks for me. I guess karma strikes again :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221994/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-christoffer).

Comment: could you share the image that you want to implement?